# How to generate mouse event on selecting table rows?

Tags: javascript

How can mouse event be generated on selecting multiple rows?

[image]

I need to catch this event and pass this to somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Please provide the code for this table.

Answer (score 1):

Look this one

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent

```
 var tableCellElement =  
 evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    tableCellElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about what tables you want to detect multiple select, what javascript library you are using if so.

Generally, you can set 2 attributes on each cell - x cordinates and y cordinates.
use the `onmousedown` [event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) on every cell and save the selection start cordinates.
use the `onmouseup` [event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) on every cell and save the selection end cordinates and see if they are the same row/cell.